# How do I get model binding to work with a custom object in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, model-binding

I'd like to adopt ASP.NET MVC Model binding for a rich client application. I have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(User profile)
```

Previously with HTML forms, as long as the form HTML input names match the names of the properties of `User`, model binding happens automatically.

I understand model binding also looks in route data and the `querystring` for values to bind to an entity, but when I put querystring values that match the properties, I get a `404`.

I can't get this `ActionResult` to ever work. Do I need to configure a route with the parameters matching the properties of the user class?

Comment: what rich client platform are you using? Is it POSTing or GETting that URL? What does the URL look like exactly?

Comment: Thanks Mauricio the rich client is Silverlight, no work has been done on the client so far as the project is just kickstarting. We are jsut currently building the back end. Thanks for the reminder, will accept the previous questions

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement custom model binder (IModelBinder interface). Then you can use it like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser([ModelBinder(typeof(MyUserModelBinder))]User profile)
```

or register it as global model binder on application start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(User)] = new MyUserModelBinder();
```

But perhaps first you should look how [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) works.
I think if you name you input fields like "profile.Name", "profile.Gender", it should work fine.